# exec does not execute correctly in PHP

Tags: php, cmd

I am using a PHP file to run a cmd command, but the command does not execute correctly, what may be the cause?

my php file executes the cmd command:

```
<?php
exec("C:\wamp\php\php.exe -e C:\wamp\htdocs\Me\mail.php me@gmail.com you");
?>
```

the mail.php file:

```
<?php
$subject = "Please check out";
$headers = "From: chico@uniserveit.com\n";

$content = "First check"; 
$fp = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/Me/checking.txt","wb"); 
fwrite($fp,$content); 
fclose($fp);

mail($argv[0], $subject, $argv[1], $headers);
?>
```

neither the file is created or the mail is sent, I think the command was not executing correctly, so how should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe function **exec()** is disabled in your configuration.

Check param **disabled_function** in your php.ini and try to turn off safemode in httpd.conf
**php_admin_value safe_mode off**

Comment: exec is not disabled in the disabled_function. And I cannot find php_admin_value in httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

In you first example, you should be using / in the string passed to exec instead of \.  \ is used to escape characters and will not work as a path separator. If you must have a \ in the string you must escape it, as in "c:\\abc\\def".  You actually tried to execute "C:wampphpphp.exe -e C:wamphtdocsMemail.php me@gmail.com you", which most likely fails to execute.  Add the second and third arguments to exec(), and then check the third for an error return value.

In the second bit of code, the file you created is never referenced.

Comment: So you mean I should use \\ instead of \?

Comment: I have changed it like this exec("C:/wamp/php/php.exe -e C:/wamp/htdocs/Me/mail.php me@gmail.com you"); but still no mail was sent and txt file was not created.

Comment: Since you are on a windows box, that would probably be the best choice (yes).

Comment: Have you tried running "C:\wamp\php\php.exe -e C:\wamp\htdocs\Me\mail.php me@gmail.com you" at a command prompt?

Comment: I have tried \\ and /, but still no response, the mail.php does not execute. I run the php file in a browser

Comment: Try the command at a command prompt.  You will see any error messages caused by an error in the command or in php allowing you to execute mail.php.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14497/discussion-between-walrii-and-user1502740)